# restarting kube-proxy wating for conditions

Tags: kubernetes, windows-10, minikube

While running the minikube start in windows 10, getting the following error.

> Error : Error restarting cluster:  restarting kube-proxy: waiting for kube-proxy to be up for configmap update: timed out waiting for the condition

Please help me resolve the give issue, I delete the minikube and restarted many time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I faced the same issue on Centos 7

`minikube delete`

then

`minikube start`

solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on mac os, tried almost everything but finally, this comment on GitHub saved my life :)

[see steps](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3031#issuecomment-448174977)

Now minikube has started as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below steps works for me :

Note : Do not work with **root** user

```
$ sudo minikube stop

$ sudo minikube delete

$ sudo rm -rf ~/.minikube

$ sudo minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.12.4
```

you can specify any existing kubernetes version of your choice with prefix **v** compulsory

make sure **.minikube** directory created in users home directory but not in **/root**